# How to get data reuse distance based on JAVA bytecode?

Tags: java, stack, bytecode

I have got java bytecode by hotspot `./hotspot -XX:+TraceBytecodes -jar HelloWorld.jar`. Now I want to get the data reuse distance, but opcode does not give variable name. So I have to trace stack values to define variable. How to trace stack values of java bytecode?
The bytecode is like this:

```
    [1435280] static void ZFArray.main(jobject)
    [1435280]  4028364     0  iconst_3
    [1435280]  4028365     1  newarray int
    [1435280]  4028366     3  astore_1
    [1435280]  4028367     4  iconst_0
    [1435280]  4028368     5  istore_2
    [1435280]  4028369     6  iload_2
    [1435280]  4028370     7  aload_1
    [1435280]  4028371     8  arraylength
    [1435280]  4028372     9  if_icmpge 22
    [1435280]  4028373    12  aload_1
    [1435280]  4028374    13  iload_2
    [1435280]  4028375    14  iconst_5
    [1435280]  4028376    15  iastore
    [1435280]  4028377    16  iinc #2 1
    [1435280]  4028378    19  goto 6
    [1435280]  4028379     6  iload_2
```

It seems like "ASM" can be used to manipulate java bytecode, but I don't know how to trace stack values for each bytecode instruction.

Comment: What do you intent to do with the “data reuse distance”? The code you’ve posted just creates an `int[]` array of length `3` and assigns `5` to all elements. I’m not sure whether the term “data reuse distance” has a meaning for this operation at all…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your attention!
Yes, this is an example. I want to calculate data reuse of algorithms such as Bayes and Kmeans. (i) Local variable #index is reused in javabyte code. (ii) Besides, the index of array can not be identified by java bytecode, which can identified by stack change. So I need to get variable name and index to caculate data reuse.